# WordPress.org: How to add a plugin for certain countries?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wordpress.org

I wrote my plugin, which I would like to share with the WP community. I would like to post it on the site of `Wordpress.org` for this. But my plugin is intended only for certain countries, since only for users in these countries this plugin may be interesting.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to add a plug-in only for certain countries?
2. Description of the plugin and other information about it must be written in English, or I can use another language (Russian)?

Comment: I think that both are impossible.

Comment: @Ranuka maybe you know where I can read rules/faq about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [no formal requirement](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/) that your plugin use English as its language. [Here](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/russian-number-comments/) is an example of a Russian only plugin.

The plugin repository at wordpress.org is global. You cannot restrict distribution to certain countries. And even if you could, the open source license would allow others to do so. If you release your software under a GPL license, which you must agree to to use the repository, you wave certain rights. One of those is the right to control who is using your software and where.

Comment: Thx man! But this can cause problems to consider the plugin support service?

Comment: You are supposed to support your plugin yourself, so users will contact you in your language. I have no idea if there are Russian speaking people at the repository who decide on Russian language plugins. There probably are. On the other hand, English is the language of the international WordPress community, so it would be polite to include at least some description of what your plugin does in English.